# Extract data from OSM url using QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I want to import this map http://hikebikemap.org/ into QGIS 3.0 and extract a specific country. Is this possible and if yes how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't. You said in title you want the `OSM data` and the question is asking for the `map`. Are different things. The map is data + styles and it is very hard to achieve this quality because the shading came from SRTM data. You can try to import OSM data but `this map` you will not have without a hard work.

Comment: Yes you are right I need the map and specific all of Greece is this possible without the huge work maybe with a plugin in QGIS or another stand alone one?.

Comment: Do you want the image at some resolution or the vector data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hikebikemap is just another way of displaying OSM data. To get an entire country's worth of OSM data, look on [geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/).

To get something out of the OSM data that more closely resembles the map you link to, you'll have to create some layer styling rules. The folks who put that map together actual detail the particular tags they use to create it, which you can read about [here](https://cycling.waymarkedtrails.org/help/rendering).

Essentially, you need to look for cycling route tags, and include those in your styling rules using a statement like `"ATTRIBUTE" IN('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'...)`. In addition to the tags used in this map, you may be interested in OSM's own [wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Cycle_routes#Tagging_cycle_route_networks) that lays out all the cycle route tags currently in use globally.

As Magno C points out in his comment, getting a nice-looking result will require a bit of effort on your part, and getting a nice baselayer under your vectors will involve some other data source, and may depend somewhat on the country you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The QuickMapServices plugin let you add the exact same basemap in qgis
(in two layers : the map and the hillshading) but this is raster data so if it's for print the quality could be disapointing

[image]

(you have to search for ''hike'' in the Search QSM window)

Another way could be to use the Vector Tiles Reader Plugin with a free key from OpenMapTiles to get a vector base map (see the help from the plugin for these steps, the ''Basic'' style seem appropriate) then extract only the relevant information from OSM (bike path and maybe some road and place-name).

This way you would have minimal styling and still end with a print quality vector map

Comment: Thank you I have successfully imported the hike bike map :). I need the data to do some queries using them not for printing so the quality doesn't care me.